# which one consume less resources? opening text file or make an sql query,both a thousand times?

Tags: php, sql, file-io

I've a php website which displays recipes [www.trymasak.my](http://www.trymasak.my), to be exact. The recipes being displayed at the index page is updated about once a day. To get the latest recipes, I just use a mysql query which is something like "select recipe_name, page_views, image from table order by last_updated". So if I got 10000 visitors a day, obviously the query would be made 10000 times a day. A friend told me a better way (in terms of reducing server load) is when I update the recipes, I just put in the latest recipe details (names,images etc) into a text file, and make my page instead of querying a same query for 10,000 times, just get the data from the text file. Is his suggestion really better? If yes, which is the best php command should I use to open, read and close the text file?

thanks

Comment: That is one query each 8 seconds, that is no problem at all with any solution.

Answer (score 3):

The typical solution is to cache in memory. Either the query result or the whole page.

Comment: @imin, I'm not a php guru, but Memcached seems to be your best option for storing query results in memory. For caching whole pages you should probably twiddle with your web server.

Answer (score 3):

## Benchmark

To know the truth about something you should really benchmark it. "Simple is Hard" from Rasmus Ledorf(Author of PHP) are really interesting [video](http://www.archive.org/details/simple_is_hard)/[slides](http://talks.php.net/show/drupal08)(my opinion ;)) which explain how to benchmark your website. It will teach you to tackle the low hanging fruit of your website instead of wasting your time doing premature optimizations.

> Donald Knuth made the following two
>   statements on optimization: "We should
>   forget about small efficiencies, say
>   about 97% of the time: [premature
>   optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization) is the root of all evil"
>
> "In established engineering
>   disciplines a 12 % improvement, easily
>   obtained, is never considered marginal
>   and I believe the same viewpoint
>   should prevail in software
>   engineering"[5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP_accelerator)

In a nutshell you will run benchmarks using tools like [Siege](http://www.joedog.org/index/siege-home), ab, httperf, etc. I would really like to advice you to watch this video if you aren't familiar with this topic, because I found it a really interesting watch/read.

## Speed

If speed as your concern you should have at least consider:

1. Using a [bytecode cache => APC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP_accelerator). Precompiling your PHP will really speed up your website for at least these two big reasons:

   > Most PHP accelerators work by caching
   >   the compiled bytecode of PHP scripts
   >   to avoid the overhead of parsing and
   >   compiling source code on each request
   >   (some or all of which may never even
   >   be executed). To further improve
   >   performance, the cached code is stored
   >   in shared memory and directly executed
   >   from there, minimizing the amount of
   >   slow disk reads and memory copying at
   >   runtime.
   >
   > PHP accelerators can substantially
   >   increase the speed of PHP
   >   applications. Improvements of web page
   >   generation throughput by factors of 2
   >   to 7 have been observed. 50
   >   times faster for compute intensive
   >   analysis programs.
2. Us an in-memory database to store your queries => [Redis](http://redis.io) or [Memcached](http://memcached.org). [There is a very very big mismatch between memory and the disc(IO)](http://books.google.nl/books?id=xfYMoFsX3vsC&pg=PA140&lpg=PA140&dq=memory+vs+io+speed+mismatch&source=bl&ots=PmIv26QJeR&sig=QVCRfUgQ5s0RKqkkxmwNzuJxCDQ&hl=nl&ei=7M1cTcr_N8OeOvi-lfAK&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=7&sqi=2&ved=0CEMQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q&f=false).

   > Thus, we observe that the main memory
   >   is about 10 times slower and I/O units
   >   1000 times slower than the processor.

   The analogy part is also interesting read(can't copy from google books :)).

Answer (score 1):

Databases are more flexible, secure and scalable in the long run. 10000 queries per day isn't really that much for modern RDBMS either. Go (or stay) database.

Optimize on the caching side of things, the HTTP specification has an own section on that:

- http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html

Answer (score 0):

Reading files:

- [file_get_contents()](http://lv.php.net/file_get_contents), if you want
  to store contents in a variable
  before outputting
- [readfile()](http://lv.php.net/readfile), if
  you just want to output file's
  contents

Answer (score 0):

If you try it, store the recipes in a folder structure like this:

/recipes/X/Y/Z/id.txt
where X, Y and Z is a random integer, from 1 to 25

example:
/recipes/3/12/22/12345.txt

This is because the filesystem is just another database. And it has a lot more hidden meta data updates to deal with.

I think MySQL will be faster, and certainly more manageable, since you'd have to backup the MySQL db anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Opening ONE file is faster that doing a mysql connect + query.
BUT, if your website already needs a mysql connect to retreive some other informations, you probably want to stick with your query because the longuest part is the connection and your query is very light.

On the other hand, opening 10 files is longer than query 10 records from a database, because you only open one mysql connection.

In any case, you have to consider how long is your query and if caching it in a text file will have more pros than cons.